# Ruby on Rails db migrate error while loading the hoe gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rubygems

I have been having this problem the whole day. whenever i try to do a rake db:migrate command on rails i keep getting this error. 
"error while loading the hoe gem.
Please install it by running the following:
$ [sudo] gem install hoe".

But everytime i run and update all my gems i still get the same error.
The hoe gems i have already installed is the latest version (hoe 3.15.3)
Please help.
Am running rails 5.0.0.1[this is the error i keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCsp9.png)

Comment: Can you tell us the version of rake that you use ?
`

Comment: Do you have the same issue when you `bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

Comment: I am using rake version 12.0.0

Comment: I still have the same issue even when i try 'bundle exec rake db:migrate'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct version? check your `Gemfile`.

Use `bundle install` to install correct version

Comment: Just checked my Gemfile. and the hoe gem is not listed. Should i just edit it in a text editor or is that a bad idea.

Comment: sorry i am still at rails 4 and have no idea what than gem does.

Comment: Ok thank you though i'll just have to downgrade my rails version

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found a way around it. I just deleted the previous app folder, created a new one and the problem was fixed. Good thing i was just starting out.